# Universal Robots Driver ROS2 not working

Tags: ros, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to control an UR5 Robot arm using ROS2.
To achieve this i've been using the following repo as guideline:
https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/tree/humble

I'm running this on Ubuntu 22.04.02 and using ROS2 Humble

When i try to launch the driver i get the following logs:

```
ros2 launch ur_robot_driver ur_control.launch.py ur_type:=ur5 robot_ip:=10.100.129.39 launch_rviz:=false

[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ur-control/.ros/log/2023-06-27-15-10-38-716282-u22lts-urcontrol-46884
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [dashboard_client-2]: process started with pid [46889]
[INFO] [controller_stopper_node-3]: process started with pid [46891]
[INFO] [ur_ros2_control_node-1]: process started with pid [46887]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [46893]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [46895]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [46897]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [46899]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [46901]
[INFO] [spawner-9]: process started with pid [46930]
[INFO] [spawner-10]: process started with pid [46937]
[dashboard_client-2] [INFO] [1687871439.398742580] [UR_Client_Library]: Connected: Universal Robots Dashboard Server
[dashboard_client-2] 
[controller_stopper_node-3] [INFO] [1687871439.398103120] [Controller stopper]: Waiting for switch controller service to come up on controller_manager/switch_controller
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   what():  text not specified in the tf_prefix tag
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.427927325] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428226479] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428249023] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link_inertia
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428257832] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment flange
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428265292] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forearm_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428272157] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ft_frame
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428278847] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment shoulder_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428285812] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment tool0
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428292984] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment upper_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428301409] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428312288] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wrist_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428322226] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wrist_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1687871439.428332326] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wrist_3_link
[ERROR] [ur_ros2_control_node-1]: process has died [pid 46887, exit code -6, cmd '/home/ur-control/workspace/ros_ur_driver/install/ur_robot_driver/lib/ur_robot_driver/ur_ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_v5mj3prx --params-file /home/ur-control/workspace/ros_ur_driver/install/ur_robot_driver/share/ur_robot_driver/config/ur5e_update_rate.yaml --params-file /home/ur-control/workspace/ros_ur_driver/install/ur_robot_driver/share/ur_robot_driver/config/ur_controllers.yaml'].
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1687871441.826413906] [spawner_forward_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1687871441.848227602] [spawner_scaled_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1687871441.886653953] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1687871441.903905257] [spawner_force_torque_sensor_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1687871441.911055867] [spawner_speed_scaling_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1687871441.920189700] [spawner_io_and_status_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1687871443.849888060] [spawner_forward_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1687871443.871522619] [spawner_scaled_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1687871443.910050317] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1687871443.926036279] [spawner_force_torque_sensor_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1687871443.934576269] [spawner_speed_scaling_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1687871443.943109006] [spawner_io_and_status_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1687871445.872573721] [spawner_forward_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1687871445.892843767] [spawner_scaled_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1687871445.932238611] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1687871445.946847240] [spawner_force_torque_sensor_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1687871445.956192171] [spawner_speed_scaling_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1687871445.966376156] [spawner_io_and_status_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1687871447.894589500] [spawner_forward_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1687871447.915575034] [spawner_scaled_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1687871447.954223894] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1687871447.968323321] [spawner_force_torque_sensor_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1687871447.978319658] [spawner_speed_scaling_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1687871447.989146442] [spawner_io_and_status_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-10] [ERROR] [1687871449.917023615] [spawner_forward_position_controller]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-5] [ERROR] [1687871449.939288109] [spawner_scaled_joint_trajectory_controller]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1687871449.974735907] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-9] [ERROR] [1687871449.990382404] [spawner_force_torque_sensor_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-8] [ERROR] [1687871450.001533371] [spawner_speed_scaling_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1687871450.012905398] [spawner_io_and_status_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-10]: process has died [pid 46937, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner forward_position_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --inactive --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 46895, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner scaled_joint_trajectory_controller -c /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 46897, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-9]: process has died [pid 46930, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner force_torque_sensor_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-8]: process has died [pid 46901, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner speed_scaling_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 46899, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner io_and_status_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args'].
```

I've also tried using the recommended IP settings, however this did not make any difference. I'm pretty confident that the communication between the UR5 and my PC is working, since i was able to extract some callibration data using this comand:

```
$ ros2 launch ur_calibration calibration_correction.launch.py \
robot_ip:=<robot_ip> target_filename:="${HOME}/my_robot_calibration.yaml"
```

Im very much a noob at ROS but i'm pretty sure that the issue lies with the 'tf_prefix' variable somehow or there is an issue with missing packages.
If anyone can help me solve this or give me some pointers to find the issue, i would be very thankfull.

I've followed this section of the documentation to install and setup my workspace:
https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/tree/humble#build-from-source

Heres some additional information about my ROS enviroment:

```
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_DISTRO=humble
```

If any other information would be helpfull, i will be happy to provide it asap.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416924/universal-robots-driver-ros2-not-working/) by [ledrag](https://answers.ros.org/users/156115/ledrag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-06-27**:
Looks like [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver#718](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/issues/718).

As this is an actual problem with the sw, as opposed to some configuration or usage question, I'd recommend diagnosing on the issue tracker instead of here on ROS Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a follow-up: This has been resolved in the driver. See https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/issues/677

---

Originally posted by [fexner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26760/fexner/) with karma: 221 on 2023-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0